# Is there a way to prevent spreadsheet from updating the date to today's date in formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm trying to print the date when I change the value on a cell (status column). But `spreadsheets` update the date to today's date. I wish it could save the date from when the status was changed.

The code to print the date:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {

  var today = new Date();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT-3', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  return date;

}
```

In the spreadsheet, the column `D` is where I set the status and columns `H` to `J` print the date from when the status was changed.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The code for column `H` is the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(H:H)=1;"Logística";IF(ISBLANK(D:D);;IF((D:D>=3)*(D:D<6);TIMESTAMP();IF(D:D<1;"Aguardando Pagamento";IF(D:D=2;"Aguardando Etiqueta";IF(D:D=6;"Cancelado";"Aguardando Faturamento")))))))
```

The codes for columns `I` and `J` are similar to `H`. So, how to print the date from when the status in column `D` was changed and keep `spreadsheet` from updating to today's date?

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to create Google Apps Script code that runs every time the spreadsheet changes (using the onEdit event - guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)).

The problem with your approach is that in general, all spreadsheet cells get recalculated when their source cells change, thus updating its contents.